# Update FlexSlider2 width when container width is set to 100% on button click

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, resize, flexslider

I am using FlexSlider2 on a fixed width site, but am trying to make a button for a "full screen" view. Basically, all the button does is change the main site's container div to be 100% width and hide other site elements.

Here is my code for the button's function:

```
    $('.fullscreen-toggle').click(function() {
        $('#container').toggleClass('full-width', 0);
        $('#header').toggleClass('hide', 0);
        $('#menu').toggleClass('hide', 0);
        $('#lower-content').toggleClass('hide', 0);
        $('.fullscreen-toggle span').toggle();
    });
```

The problem I'm having is FlexSlider only adjusts its image/slide width when the window is resized or when it's brought in and out of focus (by changing browser tabs). I've been unable to find a way to "reload" FlexSlider when the button is clicked so the images are full width. Right now when the button is clicked multiple slides are shown at a time, like this: http://img202.imageshack.us/img202/5308/flexsliderresizeissue.jpg

Things I've tried:

- This plugin: benalman (com) /projects/jquery-resize-plugin/ (link removed to meet min link requirement)
- Using .load() to try to refresh the script (don't think that's the intended function of .load, but I tried anyway :S)
- Including the `$('#slider').flexslider();` call in the .click() function again
- Other variations of the things above, and maybe some I can't even remember! I've been at this for awhile now

I apologize I can't link directly to the site, but if you need anymore information please let me know.

**Update**
Adding `$('ul.slides li').css("width", $('#container').width() + "px");` to my .click function gets the images to be the right size, however, two slides are still shown at once. This time they're split perfect in half.

**Update 2**
Flexslider CSS: http://pastebin.com/zVk82NkK

Answer (score 0):

On flexslider.css file do you have this line?

```
.flexslider .slides img {width: 100%; display: block;}
```

I think that keeping `width: 100%` is enough to have only 1 image sliding each time.

Comment: I do have that in my CSS, I've added my CSS file to the original question, too. Making the li tags the same width as the container solved my size issue, now it's just getting the slides to align correctly again.